# Proving the corrolary of the Archimedean Principle

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Theorem: For every positive real number $ε$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<ε$ for all $n \ge N$.

Proof:

Since $\frac{1}{n}<ε$,

$ε⋅n>1$

if we let $n=\frac{k}{ε}$, where $k$ is a real number and $k>1$, this inequality holds true.

$\frac{k}{ε}$ must also be greater than or equal to some positive integer $N$.

We can let $N=\lfloor{}\frac{k}{ε}\rfloor$ because $\lfloor{}x\rfloor \le x$ for all real number $x$. Also, since $ε$  is positive, $\frac{k}{ε}$ can't get smaller than $0$, thus choosing $N=0$ works for all positive real numbers $ε$.

I think the proof is completed here, so I put the black square ■.
This is my first attempt to write a formal(ish) proof, feel free to tell me how I could write a more elegant or perhaps even more correct proof.

Comment: No, $N=0$ certainly does not work. Say $\epsilon=\frac13$, $n=2$. Then $n>N=0$, so $\frac12=\frac1n<\epsilon=\frac13$????

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wrote that n must equal to k/ε, where k is a real number greater than 1 and ε a positive real number, greater than 0. This fraction is always greater than 0, and since n must be greater than or equal to N, I think letting N=0 works fine. In the example you presented, since ε is equal to 1/3, n must equal to 3k, and since k is greater than 1, the inequality holds. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Since $k>1$ the inequality holds? You're saying that $n>1$ implies $\frac12<\frac13$.

Comment: n=k/ε - not necessarily n>1, 1/n = ε/k, 

ε/k < ε, inequality holds true because k>1

Comment: You're not making any sense. "Since $n$ must be greater than or equal to $N$, $N=0$ works. No. That would make sense if "$N$ works" meant "$n>N$". But you're not trying to prove $n>N$! You're supposed to show that for **every** $n>N$ you have $\frac1n<\epsilon$.

Comment: If $\epsilon=\frac12$ then $N=0$ **does not** "work". Saying it works says that $\frac1n<\epsilon$ for **every** integer $n>0$; $n=1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I finally understood your point. You are right, N=0 does not work in the case where ε = 1/3. N should be sufficiently large, and I think n≥N should be replaced by n>N or I should find N with a different way than using the floor function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good first attempt, but there are definitely some issues. Most are a matter of presentation, but some run deeper.

- The first sentence fragment, "Since $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$," is a problem. You don't know if such an $n$ exists yet! In fact, the point is to construct such an $n$ (using the Archimedean principle).
  That said, this is likely a presentation issue. The rest of the proof seems to have the right thrust to it, and understands that $n$ needs to be constructed. Perhaps a better way of wording would be, "Such an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ satisfies $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$, or equivalently, $n \varepsilon > 1$.
- "If we let $n = \frac{k}{\varepsilon}$..."
  This is fine, so long as $\frac{k}{\varepsilon}$ is an integer! If $\varepsilon$ is irrational (which it could be), then there will be no such $k$. However, once again, your proof seems to start dealing with this in the next couple of lines, so again, it might just be an issue with presentation.
- "$\frac{k}{\varepsilon}$ must also be greater than or equal to some positive integer $N$"
  This isn't quite what the archimedean principle says. It guarantees $\frac{k}{\varepsilon}$ must be **lesser** or equal to some positive integer $N$. This is actually good news! We want $\frac{k}{\varepsilon} \le N$, so that $1 < k \le \varepsilon N$, and so $\varepsilon > \frac{1}{N}$. This $N$ is the $n$ you need to construct!
- On the previous point, there's no need to consider general $k > 1$. Just consider $k = 2$. That is, find positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{2}{\varepsilon} \le N$, and everything will work out. It's not a big deal, but introducing fewer unnecessary variables makes the proof slicker.
- As for the final point, $N = 0$ is frequently not considered a positive integer. Besides, it won't satisfy $n\varepsilon > 1$, and more concerningly, it would make $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$ nonsensical!
- There's also a potential issue with using floor (and ceiling) functions, because this function relies on the Archimedean principle. If you've shown that these functions are well-defined, using this principle, then you can use them. However, you shouldn't need to use them; using the principle directly is very simple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here are my takeaways:
1. To start the proof, it's better to write "Let's assume there's a number n that satisfies.." or something similar to show the goal is to construct such a number
2. I think I forgot to note that n is a real number greater than an integer N
3. Using k=2 and moving generalization to the end (or omitting) would avoid unnecessary clutter and make the proof more readable
4. N=0 was a needless and as David pointed out in comments, erroneous addition
5. Floor function is unnecessary